# asp.net login status changing throughout

Tags: iis, authentication, logout, loginstatus

I currently have two applications in IIS and am trying to run them both in the same Internet Explorer browser window. It all works fine when I log into one application, however when I log into the other one, the previous applications 'Logout' asp.net link changes to a 'Login' link.

I think I need to alter the session state settings, but am not sure what needs changing or how I can fix this?

I would be very grateful if anybody could help me with this please!

Thanks in advance